# Adjust ggplot starting point

Tags: r, ggplot2

ggplot tick problem

[image: 1]

Print figures using ggplot2 and grid.arrange.
Depending on the number of characters in ylabel, the starting point of the graph is different.
Code needs to be modified to specify the same starting point

And to set the starting point of the x-axis in the vector data

Comment: Have you considered using the {patchwork} package for plot composition?